# Disadvantages of using triac to control inverter load

Tags: inverter, solar-energy

I'm trying to optimise the usage of a residential solar system. It's a fairly low capacity system connected to the grid with an inverter (no batteries). There is also resistive heater which uses, on average, 1-2kW, which is less than the capacity of the solar panels/inverter. However, it simply uses a thermostat to switch on and off, and the heating element is 3-4kW, significantly above the solar system's capacity (duty cycle is approximately 50%).

My question is, is it ok to use a triac style dimmer to limit the power going to the heater? I know it shouldn't be a problem for the heater, since it's just resistive, but what about the inverter? Will it be ok since it's a grid-tie inverter? Will it basically result in high frequency spikes of mains usage, or will the capacitors in the inverter even this out and make it work as intended? Is the EMI likely to be a problem due to switching a high power device?

If it's relevant, the max/min power factor of the inverter is ±0.8. If you could include in your answer why the power factor is/isn't relevant that would be great, because I always struggle a bit with power factors. Also note I am not proposing building a dimmer myself, just buying one.

Comment: What would be the purpose of limiting the heater power? That will just make it run longer (i.e., higher duty cycle), and in the end, it will consume essentially the same amount of energy. Besides which, if you want to use solar energy for heating, there are far better ways to do that without converting it to electricity first.

Comment: @DaveTweed It's useful in countries where utility meters don't run backwards

Comment: @bobflux: In such countries, grid-tied systems don't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @DaveTweed It depends, sure it makes things more complicated, but it works fine. You have to control loads to consume your production in real time, which is what OP is asking.

Comment: It would be cheaper to find a heater that consumes 1kW or so, and to set its thermostat five or ten degrees higher than the big heater's thermostat.  Then, when the solar power is sufficient, just the little heater will run.  When the solar power _isn't_ sufficient, about the time you're putting on a sweater, the big heater will kick in.

Comment: If you're _only_ using solar to heat your house, it may be more effective to install some solar heating panels -- the ones that folks were using in the 1970's that ran fluid through black pipes inside of 100mm-tall "greenhouses".

Comment: @bobflux is right, I'm trying to balance the instantaneous load. I know there are other solutions, such as changing the heating system or the heating element, but that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: @TimWescott Thermal solar is 4x more efficient but costs per surface area are 4-10x more than photovoltaic and plumbing is cumbersome and expensive. So output watts end up costing the same or close, but electricity is a lot more versatile than low temperature heat. 400W PV panel costs 100€ these days.

Comment: That said if you don't like harmonics you could use a variac, for the steampunk factor. My old water heater perforated so I got a new one, it has a "three phase compatible resistor" which really means 3 resistors wired in parallel. I'm going to use that to make 3-level "dimming".

Comment: Oooh, yes!  A variac and an inner loop using a position servo!  What could go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering both your question and Dave Tweed's comment, so I'll start with some useful details because not all countries manage PV in the same way...

- You have a low power grid tied solar installation (say 2 kWp)
- You have a heater using 4kW with low duty cycle.

Presumably your utility meter does not count backwards, or counts energy imported from and exported to the grid in two different bins with different prices, one of them being potentially zero. For example in France you can give a few kW to the grid, the meter will count your score in the "export" tab, but it's not substracted from your bill unless you have a special contract. If you do not, it's useless. If you do, the price you sell that power back to the grid is "meh not worth it".

In your case, which is usual:

- When the heater is on, the meter sees (4kW load - 2kW solar) = 2kW import, which it bills
- When the heater is off, the meter sees 2kW solar = 2kW export, which it does not refund

So you still pay for 50% of the energy to heat that resistor even though you produce enough to not pay anything, because of duty cycle and accounting subtleties.

Anyway. Like everyone else who has PV now you want a solar router/diverter!

**TODO: google "DIY solar diverter" for a ton of projects.**

If you use a triac, say with a duty cycle of 50%, the following will happen:

- Your inverter will be absolutely fine and won't notice anything special.

If you use a grid tied inverter, your load current does not go through the inverter. Instead, the inverter monitors grid voltage, synchronizes to it, and injects sinewave **current** into the grid. The triac dimmer may make the voltage waveform a bit uglier, but that won't bother the inverter.

If your inverter is linked to a smartmeter, it will see the house is drawing more power due to the heater, and will attempt to produce more power (if available from solar panels).

- The utility meter will notice power flows in "export" direction when the triac dimmer is off, and in the "import" direction when the triac dimmer is on.

Residential utility meters usually bill active power only. This means they have to count the total energy used per period and bill that. During a period, power may flow in both directions, but only the total amount of energy transferred during a period counts.

Current meter chipsets (I read the datasheets) do not distinguish solar plus a triac dimmed load, or a big reactive load with a terrible power factor, like a motor. The energy metering chip just computes \$ \int v(t) i(t) \$ and does not care about the rest.

So it will work fine.

The only consequences are:

1. Every time it switches, the triac will inject a high frequency noise spike into the grid, which may manifest as buzzing in your hifi. Please look up "Triac noise suppression", you will need an inductor for this, easy to DIY, you will need a very large iron powder core.
2. The distorted current waveform will create harmonics. This is a bit rude towards the grid, but you most likely won't be billed for it. If your grid connection has high resistance, this will manifest as harmonics on your voltage, which means your motors may act as loudspeakers and emit weird buzz/growl sounds.

The triac solution is nice because you can control it easily: measure power exported by the house, and adjust the phase angle so all the power that would be exported to the grid is used by the heating element instead.

The "civilized" solution is to use a pure sine wave dimmer ; these are usually more expensive than the amount they will save on your electricity bill. Fronius sells one for 1k€ for example.

There are other solutions, for example if your 4kW heating element is actually a three phase resistor, you can rewire the three resistors in series so it will use much less power. The thermostat will do its job so it will simply heat for a longer time, for the same end result, but it will use more power from solar.

**Under no circumstances should you ever use diodes to reduce power used by a load** as that will draw DC current, which may saturate the utility transformer.

However the real answer is: install more solar panels.

Comment: Thanks @bobflux, that's an excellent explanation! Yes, I as you say, I can sell back to the grid but at a very reduced price. One query: when you say "per period", I assume you mean one period of the sine wave, 1/50 of a second (UK)? Do all meters work like this or should I try to find a datasheet for this one?

Comment: Yes 1/50s since we live in 50Hz land. I can't be sure all meters work like this, but in order to bill active power only (not reactive) for all types of loads, it has to compute integral of current x voltage over each period. If you know what chip your meter uses, you can check the datasheet... or just test with a dimmer and a resistive load while the solar panels produce...